# Fit ChartJS Doughnut chart into containing div

Tags: jquery, css, canvas, chart.js

I am having an issue with fitting a ChartJS Doughnut Chart into a containing div. I'm currently using Foundation, and the containing div is a medium-3 columns. What happens is the canvas has a fixed width of 300px, and on my screen, the div it is contained in is 185px wide. Therefore, the canvas is overflowing off to the right of panel it's contained in. I haven't found a clean solution to center the canvas horizontally inside the div.

Currently, I'm using this jQuery code to position the chart on page load/resize:

```
function positionChart(){
      var pixRight = ($("#chart").width() - $("#chart").parent().width())/2 + "px";

      $("#chart").css('position', 'relative');
      $("#chart").css('right', pixRight);
      $("#chart").css('top', '15px');
    }
```

This code works, but not consistently. On many browsers besides my own that I've tested it on, the $(document).ready() function doesn't help because at the time of that event, the dimensions of the canvas and containing div are all 0. I've tried it with multiple combinations of document and window .load and .ready with no success.

My question is, how can I do this, if at all, in CSS/SASS (this view is in a Rails 3 app) or what could I do to the JS/jQuery to make sure an event is fired once the dimensions for the elements are set (so I can call the positionChart() function)? Much appreciated.